# Image extension is lost when using fileupload in fancybox

Tags: c#, jquery, asp.net, file-upload, fancybox-2

Hi I am trying to implement fileupload inside fancybox. To be more specific i want the users to upload their image just as on stackoverflow.

**Problem :** When i am uploading the pic inside the fancybox, the extension of the image is lost. However on doing the same without the fancybox effect results in a successful submission and retrieval.

**aspx code :**

```
<div class="poc1">
        <asp:Image ID="Image1" runat="server" />
        <div class="changePic">

        <a class="fancybox" href="#shadow"> Change Pic </a>
       </div>
       </div>

        <asp:Label ID="Label1" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <br /><br />
        <asp:Label ID="Label2" runat="server" Text="Label"></asp:Label>
        <br />


   <div id="shadow" style="display:none;width:300px;">

    <asp:FileUpload ID="FileUpload1" runat="server" />
    <br /><br />
    <asp:Button ID="Button1" runat="server" Text="Upload" onclick="Button1_Click" />
    <br /><br /> 
    </div>
```

**jquery :**

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        $(".fancybox").fancybox({
        parent: "form:first",

        openEffect  : 'none',
        closeEffect : 'none',
        afterLoad   : function() {
        this.content = this.content.html();
        }
        });
        </script>
```

**aspx.cs cdode :**

```
using System; using System.Collections.Generic; using System.Linq; using System.Web; using System.Web.UI; using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

using System.Data.SqlClient; using System.Configuration; using System.Web.Security;

using System.IO;

public partial class Default3 : System.Web.UI.Page {
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        string virtualFolder = "~/UserPics/";
        string physicalFolder = Server.MapPath(virtualFolder);
        string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnectionString"].ConnectionString;
        SqlConnection myConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString);

        MembershipUser currentUser = Membership.GetUser();
        Guid currentUserId = (Guid)currentUser.ProviderUserKey;

        //save old pic vlaue in string
        SqlCommand cmdSelect = new SqlCommand("SELECT [UserPicUrl] FROM [UserDetails] WHERE ([UserId] = @UserId)", myConnection);
        cmdSelect.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", currentUserId);
        myConnection.Open();
        string oldPicUrl = (string)(cmdSelect.ExecuteScalar());
        string oldPic = Server.MapPath(oldPicUrl);
        Label1.Text = "old Pic :- " + oldPic;


        //save new pic
        string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        string extension = System.IO.Path.GetExtension(FileUpload1.FileName);
        FileUpload1.SaveAs(System.IO.Path.Combine(physicalFolder, fileName + extension));
        String ImageUrl = virtualFolder + fileName + extension;
        Label2.Text = "New Pic :- " + ImageUrl;
        Image1.ImageUrl = ImageUrl;


        //update new pic in db
        SqlCommand cmdUpdate = new SqlCommand("UPDATE [UserDetails] SET [UserPicUrl] = @UserPicUrl WHERE [UserId] = @UserId", myConnection);
        cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserId", currentUserId);
        cmdUpdate.Parameters.AddWithValue("@UserPicUrl", ImageUrl);

        //delete old pic
        cmdUpdate.ExecuteNonQuery();
        myConnection.Close();
        myConnection.Dispose();
        File.Delete(oldPic);


    } }
```

Please shed a light where i am wrong, have worked on it too much but cant find a solution. Or is there any other **simple** way to have the lightbox effect around the fileupload condition.

Comment: Theoretically, the Fancy box should just be "wrapping" around existing dom elements, and the FileUpload control from ASP should be handling the file extension.  Seems like we are missing something here.  After the Lightbox loads, does the HTML inside the lightbox look correct (FileUpload and such?).

Comment: Yes sir everything looks fine, just the image name which gets inserted in the file system looses its extension. For example abc.png gets converted into ~/UserPics/2f897154-f417-4d87-a6de-df6afe592e8f which without the fancybox effect results with an .png extension.

Comment: If you set a breakpoint on postback, what is the value of : FileUpload1.FileName?